# IntelliJ is using the wrong import path

Tags: java, import, jetbrains-ide

So I have a project, that I have around 1 year now, since today IntelliJ started to have problems with the import path and I cant get it to work.

Imports like this don't work anymore:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

While such imports do:

```
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
```

After some searching around, I found out, that IntelliJ tries to import Gson from the JDK because there is also a `com.` directory there but obviously no `com.google` so it says the import cant be found even though the file exists just at another place where IntelliJ is trying to search.

So how I can move IntelliJ to actually search where the file is like it did before?

Here is where IntelliJ should be searching:
[image: Here is where IntelliJ should be searching]

Here is where it actually searches:
[image: Here is where it actually searches]

I use gradle, both `jdk` and the `.gradle` directories are in the same place next to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thats also why the lombok import works because there is no lombok. directory in the jdk so it moves to the .gradle folder where the file actually is just like gson.

You've drawn the wrong conclusion. That's just not how intellij, or any java classpath system, ever works. They search in *all* `com` packages in *all* classpath entries. As part of scanning *all* the `com` packages, it will of course hit the `com` package in core java, but this does not mean that this is the *only* place it is looking.

The right question to ask is: Why isn't it finding the jar file (or jmod file) that contains gson? And the answer to that question involves a combination of your intellij project settings and your project's build file (such as `build.gradle` or `pom.xml`). However, your question does not include any details. You'd have to elaborate on how your project and/or build are set up.